# redirect multiple domains to one domain with or without www with https using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Hi guys this code dose not work correctly

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

################## Force HTTPS & WWW ################
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
################# Contact ############################
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^contact-services.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^contactmadinaty.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^contactmadinaty.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^madinaty.city [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^madinatyrealestate.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^madinatyrealestate.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realestate-madinaty.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realestatemadinaty.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^realestatemadinaty.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.contact-madinaty.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
######################################################
```

the above code working to redirect non-www to www with https but not redirect domains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like the following help? This is working fine for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: this if only one domain I need to redirect multiple domains

Comment: This redirects all other domains to www.example.com (everything that is not www.example.com). It does work for me for multiple domains